# Is there an AWS service that provides <= 20 milliseconds query latency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, latency, dynamodb-queries, low-latency

For a use-case, my team is using DynamoDB to query a GSI. **With increasing number of rows returned, the query latency increases.**

Our code looks something like this (Java) (pretty normal)

```
        Map<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap<>();
        keyConditions.put(indexHashKeyName, new Condition()
                .withAttributeValueList(Collections.singletonList(new AttributeValue(identifier.toString())))
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ));
        QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest();
        queryRequest.setTableName(tableName);
        queryRequest.setIndexName(indexName);
        queryRequest.setKeyConditions(keyConditions);
        queryRequest.withAttributesToGet(attributesRequired);
        QueryResult result = dynamoDB.query(queryRequest);
```

Our DynamoDB table has about 4-5 attributes of type String. We use AWS KMS for encryption-at-rest, and all 4-5 attributes are present in the GSI.

We see p99 latencies on the GSI as typically 30-40ms (milliseconds) for retrieving ~30 rows of data.

Is there a good way to reduce this latency (apart from caching)? Caching is not a viable solution for the pattern of client traffic our service receives.

We were looking into a couple of options:-

1. Create a DynamoDB new table which is indexed on the GSI-hash-key, with all data stored as a JSON blob (or compressed blob). This would reduce latency since the Query would now become a GET. But this would get difficult once items grow beyond the 400KB attribute size limit.
2. Create a new DynamoDB table which is indexed on the GSI-has-key, and has a range key of 1,2,3... and everytime a blob of data exceeds 400KB, create a new range item, and do multiple GETs to retrieve multiple rows of JSON blobs. This would increase latency once too many range keys start getting created for a given hash key.
3. Using ElasticSearch to do the above (presumably ElasticSearch has less limitations of size of a document), but we're not sure whether latencies would be similar or worse than DynamoDB query latencies.

Is there any other database solution AWS provides that would help for our use-cases?

**Note**:- Our EC2 hosts are in the same region as our DynamoDB table. The latency of 30-40ms is purely for dynamoDB query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you talking about query time, not latency. If you need to improve latency you can use VPC endpoints. Actually, by default, DDB works over public internet
2. If you want to improve query time, maybe you need to change RCU capacity. Or switch to on-demand pricing

Comment: I do mean query time, not latency.. Our EC2 hosts and the DynamoDB table are both in the same AWS region. RCU consumption is fine.

Comment: If you are not using VPC endpoints your traffic to DDB goes over public internet, not inside AWS network and it could have huge impact on latency

Comment: Ohh! I'd have to check for that then

Comment: A long time later, just replying to this so it helps people viewing this question. We do not use VPC endpoints, so turns out we did route our traffic through the internet. We ended up using option 2 that I've mentioned in my question to help us get over the latency. A long time later we did onboard to using VPCs, but did not have the bandwidtch to remove the workaround DDB table and well, you know how bureaucracy goes...